# How to get container's disk usage in Kubernetes (without docker command)?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubectl

I have a Kubernetes Cluster and want to know how much disk space my containers use. I am not talking about mounted Volumes.

I can get this information by using docker commands like `docker system df -v` or `docker ps -s`, but I don't want to connect to every single worker node.

Is there a way to get a container's disk usage via `kubectl` or are there kubelet metrics where I can get this information from?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, but currently not with kubectl, you can get metrics from the [kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/), either through the kube-apiserver (proxied) or directly calling the kubelet HTTP(s) server endpoint (default port `10250`). Disk metrics are generally available on the `/stats/summary` endpoint and you can also find some [cAdvisor](https://github.com/google/cadvisor) metrics on the `/metrics/cavisor` endpoint.

For example, to get the 'usedBytes' for the first container in the first pod returned through the [kube-apiserver](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/):

```
$ curl -k -s -H 'Authorization: Bearer <REDACTED>' \
  https://kube-apiserver:6443/api/v1/nodes/<node-name>/proxy/stats/summary \
  | jq '.pods[0].containers[0].rootfs.usedBytes'
```

The Bearer token can be a service account token tied to a ClusterRole like this:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  annotations:
  name: myrole
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - nodes
  - nodes/proxy
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- nonResourceURLs:
  - /metrics
  - /api/*
  verbs:
  - get
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I am using `kops` to spin up a k8s test cluster and was able to get the token using this command: `kops get secrets --type secret admin -oplaintext`. I also found the cadvisor metric for this information `container_fs_usage_bytes`.

Answer (score 5):

Adding to Rico's answer you can use `kubectl` to set up a proxy to the API server so that you can query the API with the details of the server address and authentication taken care of.

Set up a local proxy to the API server with

```sh
kubectl proxy --port=8080
```

Then you can use a command like

```
curl http://localhost:8080/api/v1/nodes/<node-name>/proxy/stats/summary 2>/dev/null | jq '.pods[].containers[].rootfs.usedBytes'
```

which will give you a list of the rootfs usage by each container.

Answer (score 2):

To add on to Stephen's answer, here is a curl query if you want the pod name alongside the size in bytes.

```
curl http://localhost:8080/api/v1/nodes/<node-name>/proxy/stats/summary 2>/dev/null | jq '.pods[].containers[] | "\(.name) \(.rootfs.usedBytes)"'
```

Answer (score 0):

As a one more addition which uses `kubectl` instead of `curl` and prints it as a table. It also prints `logs` size

```
echo -e "NODE\tNAMESPACE\tPOD\tCONTAINER\tROOTFS\tLOGS"
kubectl get --raw "/api/v1/nodes/${node}/proxy/stats/summary" | jq -r '. | .node.nodeName as $node | .pods[] | .podRef.namespace as $namespace | .podRef.name as $pod | .containers[] | [$node, $namespace, $pod, .name, .rootfs.usedBytes, .logs.usedBytes] | @tsv'
```