# List all kubernetes pods running in a worker node, sorted by disk space usage

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks, diskspace

Does anyone know how to get a sorted list of pods on a given node based on their disk space consumption?

The command below helps me in listing pods based on a given node but my requirement is to list those pods which are causing high disk space usage as part of investigating and solving the `DiskPressure` eviction state.

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide --field-selector spec.nodeName=<NODE_NAME>
```

I was able to find commands to list CPU and memory usage of nodes (ref: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/17512#issuecomment-317757388) but nothing related to node disk usage.

```
alias util='kubectl get nodes --no-headers | awk '\''{print $1}'\'' | xargs -I {} sh -c '\''echo {} ; kubectl describe node {} | grep Allocated -A 5 | grep -ve Event -ve Allocated -ve percent -ve -- ; echo '\'''

# Get CPU request total (we x20 because because each m3.large has 2 vcpus (2000m) )
alias cpualloc='util | grep % | awk '\''{print $1}'\'' | awk '\''{ sum += $1 } END { if (NR > 0) { print sum/(NR*20), "%\n" } }'\'''

# Get mem request total (we multiply by 75 because because each m3.large has 7.5G ram )
alias memalloc='util | grep % | awk '\''{print $5}'\'' | awk '\''{ sum += $1 } END { if (NR > 0) { print sum/(NR*75), "%\n" } }'\'''
```

Comment: I don't think you can get disk usage using kubectl. You can only find disk usage by exec into the pod and use linux command `du`.

Comment: Filesystem tools are better suited for your problem. Check this answer for an example. https://serverfault.com/a/994413/405997 Also common `du` might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

found an answer to my requirement - list pods disk usage running in a given node

```
kubectl get --raw /api/v1/nodes/<NODE_NAME>/proxy/stats/summary | jq '.pods[0] | "PodName: ", .podRef.name, "usedBytes: ", .containers[].rootfs.usedBytes'
```

#### Some other stats:

**get node filesystem usage**

```
kubectl get --raw /api/v1/nodes/<NODE_NAME>/proxy/stats/summary | jq '.node.fs.usedBytes'
```

**get node imageFs usage**

```
kubectl get --raw /api/v1/nodes/<NODE_NAME>/proxy/stats/summary | jq '.node.runtime.imageFs.usedBytes'
```

**get node iNodes stats**

```
kubectl get --raw /api/v1/nodes/<NODE_NAME>/proxy/stats/summary | jq '.node.fs.inodesFree'

kubectl get --raw /api/v1/nodes/<NODE_NAME>/proxy/stats/summary | jq '.node.runtime.imageFs.inodesFree'
```

Comment: Rootfs usage + logs + volumes : `kubectl get --raw /api/v1/nodes/k8s-w1/proxy/stats/summary | jq '.pods[] | "PodName: ", .podRef.name, "usedBytes:", .containers[].rootfs.usedBytes, "Logs:", .containers[].logs.usedBytes, "Volume:", .volume[].usedBytes'`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you won't be able to achieve this with `kubectl` as it does not have this kind of functionality. One way to go is login to node and the use `docker ps -s`.

Another way that I can think of is to expose kubelet/cadvisor metrics and use it with metrics scraper like [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/).

The kubelet exposes all of it’s runtime metrics, and all of the cAdvisor metrics, on a `/metrics` endpoint in the Prometheus exposition format. Note that [kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubelet) also exposes metrics in `/metrics/cadvisor`, `/metrics/resource` and `/metrics/probes` endpoints. Disk metrics are generally available on the `/stats/summary` endpoint.

Additional info:

- Stack case with great example [how to curl kubelet's endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53328104/how-to-get-containers-disk-usage-in-kubernetes-without-docker-command%29).
- Kubernetes metrics documents at [/cluster-administration/system-metrics/](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/system-metrics/)